What is the functional derivative with respect to the integration extrema?
In order to maximize the electric field transmitted through a structure I have to write a functional, then compute the functional derivatives of that functional so that I can update the geometrical parameters.
For the sake of simplicity, let's consider the functional:
$$I[d]=\int_0^d f(x) dx$$
where d is the geometrical parameter of the structure and f is a function of the electric field (I do not want to write the precise expression for f, to be more general).
In order to optimize the geometrical parameter, I need to compute the functional derivative of I with respect to d, i.e. $\delta I/\delta d$.
What is the expression for $\delta I/\delta d$?
Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you very much for your attention.
Best Regards.

Why do you need functional derivatives ? $I$ is a mere function of $d$, with $I'(d) = f(d)$.

To echo, this is a 'normal' derivative.

Do you really mean that the integral is from $0$ to $d$ or is it just bad notation?

I am greatful for all the comments. First of all, I am not so expert with functional derivatives. Is a functional derivative equal to a normal derivative if the function with respect I am deriving is a constant? If the answer is yes, I would say that the normal derivative is more than enough in this case

As for the integration from 0 to d, they are correct. Indeed the physical problem wants that the parameter d has to be optimized so that the integral of the function f (that is function of the electric field) between 0 to d has to be maximized.

Why do you want to have a functional derivative? You just want to maximize an integral. What kind of derivative you need depends on what kind of parameter you can adjust. Is it simply a real number? Then you only need a normal derivative. Is it a function? Then you need a functional derivative.
